# Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'demo_Processing.Pools'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation, sitecore-install-assistant, web-deploy

I'm trying to install Sitecore 9.2 initial-  XP single on my local machine using Sitecore Install Assistant. I installed all the prerequisites through SIA without any error but when I try to install Sitecore, I get the below error.
[image: Error]
From the SQL log, the error is a bit different from this.
[image: SQL Log]

The error comes while executing the Task 46- XconnectXP0_InstallWDP: WebDeploy
I verified the user name, password and sql server and all looks fine and able to login from Management Studio.
[image: SQL]

Local Machine Details:

- Sitecore 9.2 Initial
- MSSQL 2017 Express
- SIF 2.1.0
- Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Can you try logging into the SQL Server with the entered credentials in SIA. Once logged in, check the SQL Server Instance name. Most probably, it's not (local)\SQLExpress. It might be a computer name

Comment: Even giving the computer name did not solve the issue and I can see the error in SQL logs as in the second screenshot

Comment: Are you able to login to SSMS using the credentials which you are providing in SIA?

Comment: Yes I can, the logs screenshot I took from ssms

Comment: Can you confirm that you are running the setup.exe in Administrator mode? If not, please try running the the exe in admin mode. I'm assuming that the credentials provided above have admin rights as well. If this is not the case, please provide the SQL admin credentials for the installation

Comment: The issue I think was, even though the prerequisites installed successfully, the I web deploy 3.6 for hosting services was not installed, after installing that manually, sitecore setup completed successfully.

Comment: Ideally it should have covered as part of Prerequisites. I guess you can let Sitecore know about it through a Sitecore ticket.